# JDatePicker import statements

Tags: java, date

Ok, I know that this is going to sound very silly to most of you but I have been looking for online for hours. I want to use JDatePicker in my application so i downloaded the JDatepicker-1.3.2 jar and have added the jar to the build bath, but i have no idea what import statement to use. Can anyone help me.

```
JDatePicker datePicker = new JDatePicker();
```

Comment: I already tried that but I get the error that com.standbysoft cannot be resolved.

Comment: http://ui-programming.blogspot.in/2011/01/java-swing-date-picker-dialog-to-select.html

Comment: `import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to version 1.3.3 the import statement you require is:

```
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;
```

or

```
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.JDatePanel;
```

In future versions, the groupid of the project will change to org.jdatepicker, so if you upgrade you may need to change it to:

```
import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker
```

It is also worth mentioning that the source code has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker).

Comment: Using Spring RPC how do I integrate this DatePicker Library?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, what did you try? and what problems did you experience?

Comment: After creating a UtilDateModel instance I try to add these two other lines before I can add my field to my form: JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model); JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel), however, they remain underlined in red with some errors even when I have imported these classes at the top. I am using SpringRPC instead of native SWING.